# Click a specific submit button with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am clicking a submit button using this:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click();
```

The problem is that I have more that 1 submit button on my page so I need to target a specific submit button.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you know the number of `submit` inputs and which one (in order) you want to trigger a `click` on then you can use `nth-child()` syntax to target it. Or add an ID or a class to each one that separates them from the other.

Selecting the elements by their index:

```
$('input[type="submit"]:nth-child(1)').trigger('click');//selects the first one
$('input[type="submit"]:nth-child(2)').trigger('click');//selects the second one
$('input[type="submit"]:nth-child(100)').trigger('click');//selects the 100th one
```

There are actually several ways to do this including using `.eq()`: http://api.jquery.com/eq

Selecting the elements by their id:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_1" />
<input type="submit" id="submit_2" />
<input type="submit" id="submit_100" />

<script>
$('#submit_100').trigger('click');
</script>
```

Note that `.click()` is short for `.trigger('click')`.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer the longhand `.trigger('click')` over the shorthand?

Comment: @AntonChanning It's more of a preference than anything else. The shorthand functions are wrappers so there is a very small amount of overhead when calling them but I can't imagine it would have any noteworthy impact. I like that the `.trigger('click')` form is more descriptive, for me making it easier to quickly read code.

Comment: I'm guessing it also acts as a visual reminder of the syntax that can be used for any kind of event, including custom event types.

Answer (score 11):

If you add a marker, like a specific id or class to your `input`, you can make your selector more specific.  For example, if you give the button you want the ID of `form-btn` like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="form-btn" />
```

You can select it like this:

```
$('input[type=submit]#form-btn').click();
```

Or just:

```
$('#form-btn').click();
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `id`s to each button and select the `id` with jQuery.

Or, if the forms have `id`s, then just target the form and submit it like so:

```
$("#form-id").submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Way late to the party, but if your submit buttons have names:

```
$("input[name='submitbuttonname']").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

One other suggestion!

I had a form with multiple submits, that also had varying value attributes, so I couldn't simply submit the form after I performed my built in confirmation.

Instead, I added a few hidden buttons that I forced a click on after I got a Yes back from my confirmation.

Here are the buttons:

```
<button id="email" name="email" type="submit" class="submit radius confirmation" value="all"><?php echo $this->__('Email Receipts to Selected'); ?></button>
<button id="email-french" name="email-french" type="submit" class="submit radius confirmation" value="all"><?php echo $this->__('Email French Receipts to Selected'); ?></button>
<button id="helper-email" name="email" type="submit" class="submit hide" value="all"></button>
<button id="helper-email-french" name="email-french" type="submit" class="submit hide" value="all"></button>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('[id^=email]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var button = $(this);

        notify.confirm(<?php echo json_encode($this->__('Are you sure?')); ?>, function (ans) {
            if (ans) {
                $('#helper-' + button.attr('id')).click();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

hmm it cant work with a wizard form with this intacted

```
$("#renqform").validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
return $("#renqform").valid();
```